# Is there a way to preserve the BITMAPFILEHEADER when loading a Bitmap as a Windows resource?

Tags: c++, winapi, bitmap, resources

I've been working on testing a few things out using [SFML 1.4](http://sfml-dev.org/) (Simple and Fast Multimedia Library) with C++ and Visual C++ 2008 Express Edition.  To avoid having external images with my graphical programs, I was testing out the [sf::Image::LoadFromMemory(const char * Data, std::size_t SizeInBytes)](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/1.4/classsf_1_1Image.htm#72565ffabe12dfb2602e209c2e6f0486) function with Bitmap resources loaded using a simple resource script:

```
IDB_SPRITE BITMAP "sprite1.bmp"
```

In my code to load the image to create an [sf::Image](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/1.4/classsf_1_1Image.htm) using this bitmap resource, I use the following procedure, consisting of Win32 API functions (I've excluded the code that checks to make sure the Win32 functions don't return NULL to shorten this a bit):

```
HRSRC hResInfo = FindResource(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_SPRITE), RT_BITMAP);
HGLOBAL hResData = LoadResource(NULL, hResInfo);
char * resourceData = reinterpret_cast<char *>(LockResource(hResData));
```

After that, I use the sf::Image::LoadFromMemory function:

```
MyImage.LoadFromMemory(resourceData, SizeofResource(NULL, hResInfo));
```

However, this doesn't work (I get an unknown file type error).  After some testing, I discovered that the bitmap data I pass to the LoadFromMemory function does not include the BITMAPFILEHEADER (the first 14 bytes), and I believe this is the cause of the unknown file type error.

I can restore the BITMAPFILEHEADER manually and get the LoadFromMemory function to work fine.  **However, I'm wondering if there is some way to preserve the BITMAPFILEHEADER in the resource data to avoid doing this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a custom resource type will preserve the entire file.  Change the resource script to utilize the RCDATA type as opposed to the BITMAP type:

```
IDB_SPRITE RCDATA "sprite1.bmp"
```

In the FindResource function call, use RT_RCDATA instead of RT_BITMAP:

```
HRSRC hResInfo = FindResource(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_SPRITE), RT_RCDATA);
```

For more information:

[RCDATA Resource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381039%28VS.85%29.aspx)

[Resource Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648009%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can add file to resources as a custom resource instead of RT_BITMAP -- this will add file exactly as it is. Unless you also need to ::LoadImage() it.

Comment: Use the standard RT_RCDATA resource type instead.  Storing raw data is what it is meant for.