# Extract file from resource in Windows module

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, extract, embedded-resource

The below code executes, but it only extracts an empty bitmap file.  Any ideas as to what is wrong with it?

```
void Extract(WORD wResId , LPSTR lpszOutputPath)
{ //example: Extract(IDB_BITMAP1, "Redrose.bmp");
    HRSRC hrsrc = FindResource(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(wResId) , RT_BITMAP);
    HGLOBAL hLoaded = LoadResource( NULL,hrsrc);
    LPVOID lpLock =  LockResource( hLoaded);
    DWORD dwSize = SizeofResource(NULL, hrsrc);
    HANDLE hFile = CreateFile  (lpszOutputPath,GENERIC_WRITE,0,NULL,CREATE_ALWAYS,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,NULL);
    DWORD dwByteWritten;
    WriteFile(hFile, lpLock , dwSize , &dwByteWritten , NULL);
    CloseHandle(hFile);
    FreeResource(hLoaded);
}
```

Comment: Did you check the values of stuff like `dwSize` to make sure they are what you expected?

Comment: Did you try stepping through it under a debugger? What's getting returned from `SizeofResource`? Are you even finding the resource in the first place (i.e. does `FindResource` even find it)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are asking for `RT_RCDATA` but I bet you didn't add your bitmap via a `RCDATA` statement. You probably added it via a `BITMAP` statement, which makes it `RT_BITMAP`.

In the future, please state which step failed rather than making people guess.

Comment: thank you for pointing out my misuse of RT_RCDATA. I did not know which step failed, if I did I would not be here asking my question.  I am using RT_BITMAP and I no longer have an empty bmp but now I have an invalid bmp.

Comment: Certainly you can use the debugger to determine which step failed, right? (See the questions from Jim Buck and reuben, for example.) And the result is not a BMP file because bitmap resources are not stored in the form of a BMP file.

Comment: The debugger is telling me nothing when I step through it. If the result is not a BMP file then what is the result and what are they stored as?

Comment: The debugger doesn't show function return values and local variables? You might want to get a better debugger. As for your other question, it's indirectly answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134050/is-there-a-way-to-preserve-the-bitmapfileheader-when-loading-a-bitmap-as-a-windo) and directly [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/12/11/9935462.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in passing NULL as your HINSTANCE parameter to `FindResource`, `LoadResource`, and `SizeOfResource`.

If you have not already saved your HINSTANCE during startup (from WinMain or DllMain) you can get it using:

MFC:

```
HINSTANCE hInstance = AfxGetInstanceHandle();
```

Else:

```
HINSTANCE hInstance = (HINSTANCE)GetModuleHandle(NULL);
```

Comment: ...but according to MSDN, it's valid to pass in `NULL` if the resource you're looking for is in "the module used to create the current process"...

Comment: I tried changing NULL to hInstance noted above and still get an empty bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

Insert your raw file as a custom data.
Give this custom data a text name, example "MyType", then:

```
HRSRC hrsrc = FindResource(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(wResId) , _T("MyType"));
```

Comment: Compiler gives error C3861: '_T': identifier not found. Do I need to add an include?

Comment: OK I added tchar.h include and this fixed the error but still I am getting an empty bmp file.