# How can I self-extract a binary resource (executable) using C++?

Tags: c++, embedded-resource, self-extracting

I need to extract a binary resource (that's in my project) however, I cannot think of any way I can do it, I'm using Windows/C++.

How can I do it?

Comment: Clarify please. Do you mean an imbedded resource compiled into your .res file and linked in to your final executable/dll ?

Comment: No, I just need it to extract the file from the resources section.

Comment: And that is different.. how? "the file" is a file listed in your .rc script or not?

Comment: FindResource would be a good start. Follow the documentation from there onwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[FindResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648042%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [SizeofResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648048%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [LoadResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648046%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and [LockResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648047%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) are used in concert to gain access to "the file" held in the resource table of the module your reading. A reasonable sample of how to do this can be found at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11388134/extract-file-from-resource-in-windows-module), Note that you need to know the resource *type* and name (or ordinal), to find it for the copy.