# How to embed config files in C++ VS2015 console application instead of hard-code as const data?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, console-application

There are lots of answer about simply save it as const data or say converting it to binary data without details.

I have seen this: [How to embed a file into an executable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7288279/how-to-embed-a-file-into-an-executable)

I do not prefer converting config file into const data.

How could I embed the config file **inside the exe** when compiled but **not next to the exe**.

Detailed steps are needed.

Thank You.

Comment: config file? key->value, why don't you just hard code those value instead of embed the config file?

Comment: As I stated, I do not prefer hard-code this solution.

Comment: for hard code I meant defining some MACRO for those values, I don't see any benefit of embedding config file over using MACRO

Comment: If you're okay with a Windows-specific solution, maybe you could embed the config file as a RT_RCDATA resource?

Comment: @nomadictype I am totally okay with Windows-specific solution. It would be greatly appreciated if you could provide more details.

Comment: @AnsonWong I've added an answer with details.

Comment: Implicit in a config file is that there is a need to change it.  The worst possible place you can think of for data that needs to change is the EXE file.  An EXE file is locked for write access while the EXE is running, a side-effect of the memory-mapped view that maps the EXE content into RAM.  So you'd have to terminate the process and have *another* program that modifies the EXE.  Beyond giving anti-malware's a major wedgie, that completely does not solve the desire to deploy only one file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Windows-specific method is to embed the config file into the executable as a resource:

- Define an identifier for the resource in some header file, say `resource.h`:

  ```
  #define CONFIG_FILE_RESOURCE_ID 1
  ```
- Add a .rc file to your project with the following lines in it:

  ```
  #include "resource.h"
  CONFIG_FILE_RESOURCE_ID RCDATA "config.txt"
  ```

  where `config.txt` is the name of the file that will be embedded.
  `RCDATA` is the type of resource (custom binary data).

  Alternatively, if your version of Visual Studio comes with a
  resource editor, you could use it.
- To read the resource from within your program, you must:

  1. Call `FindResource(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(CONFIG_FILE_RESOURCE_ID), RT_RCDATA)` to get a resource handle.
  2. Call `LoadResource(NULL, hrsrc)` to convert the resource handle `hrsrc` to a `HGLOBAL`.
  3. Use the `LockResource` and `SizeofResource` functions to obtain a pointer to the data and the size of the embedded file.

  You may have to supply actual module/instance handles instead of `NULL`, especially if your code is inside a DLL.

Comment: I have tested that the config really could embed into EXE. However, I found some difficulties in reading the data from config. Can you provide an example of how to read that embedded data? Thank you.

Comment: What exactly are you having difficulties with? Did you manage to get the FindResource -> LoadResource -> LockResource -> SizeofResource dance working?

Comment: "To read the resource from within your program, you must:..."

Comment: There's some example code in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134050/is-there-a-way-to-preserve-the-bitmapfileheader-when-loading-a-bitmap-as-a-windo), just replace RT_BITMAP with RT_RCDATA. If it doesn't work, use a debugger or print out intermediate values to see which step fails.

Comment: Finally, the problem is solved with help of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9240188/how-to-load-a-custom-binary-resource-in-a-vc-static-library-as-part-of-a-dll). Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

You have to manually add the settings because visual studio doesn't know about handling config files automatically. If we do not do it manually, the config files won't be copied at the output directory.

Go to *project properties -> configuration properties -> build events -> post build event* and change the command line with:

**copy app.config"$(TargetPath).config"**

After that you have to add a new reference from *system.configuration*. Find that in *project properties -> common properties -> references -> add new reference -> .net -> system.configuraion*

Then create your config file from *project -> new -> configuration file*

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It do help me a bit. However, I want the exe itself containing that config instead of having the config next to it

Comment: @AnsonWong You simply can't compile a .exe file with .config altogether. The sole purpose of having a config file is to do manual configurations to the application (.exe) externally. You comment has a duplicate here:

Comment: @AnsonWong Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4586210/how-do-i-compile-my-app-config-into-my-exe-in-a-vs2010-c-sharp-console-app

Answer (score 0):

I understood that you want to create self modifying exe file that will store config. As a simple answer you can't achieve that without hacking page protection.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898831/can-a-c-program-modify-its-executable-file) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1954404/program-that-modifes-string-inside-its-exe) you can find some useful information.